# Not able to import SQL file on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, privileges

When I try to import an SQL file from a previous import on another database, it doesn't happen and I get the following error in the logs:

> exit status 1 ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 20: Access denied; you need
> (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I am not able to import it in any way.

How to import a sql or csv file on Google Cloud ? Both doesn't works.

Version: MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

****Cloud SQL** 2nd Generation** doesn't provide SUPER privileges to customer. If the dump contains some lines which require SUPER privilege, the import will fail.

Please, check this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv#sqldump) and follow the guide for creating  a dump that meets all the requirements for CloudSQL import.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an export from a Cloud SQL second-generation instance, you’ll need to export only the databases using the `--database` flag as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export/exporting); otherwise system tables will be included in your SQL dump file and this will lead to the error that you reported, since these tables require SUPER privileges.

If your existing dump includes any system tables, you will need to remove them before trying to import the file.